# Check length of matrix elements

Tags: r, matrix

```
mat <- structure(list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 2, c(3, 2, 1), numeric(0), numeric(0), 
    numeric(0), c(1, 2, 3, 6), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 1, numeric(0), 
    numeric(0), numeric(0), c(3, 4, 2), 3, c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
    numeric(0), numeric(0), numeric(0), numeric(0), numeric(0), 
    numeric(0), 1.358, numeric(0), numeric(0), numeric(0), numeric(0), 
    numeric(0), numeric(0), 0.0223257970827299, numeric(0), numeric(0), 
    numeric(0), numeric(0), numeric(0), numeric(0), 1.493), .Dim = c(6L, 
6L))

> mat
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]     
[1,] Numeric,5 Numeric,4 Numeric,3 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0
[2,] 2         Numeric,5 3         Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0
[3,] Numeric,3 1         Numeric,5 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0
[4,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 1.358     Numeric,0 Numeric,0
[5,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 0.0223258 Numeric,0
[6,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 1.493
```

I have a 6x6 matrix object. Each cell contains a list of numeric values. I would like to find the indices `i, j` in the `mat` object that indicate which cells contain a vector that is > 1 but < 5 elements long. In other words, I would like to see the indices: (1, 2), (1, 3), and (3, 1).

I've tried using `which(length(mat) < 5 & length(mat) > 1)` but that didn't work.

Comment: fwiw `lengths(mat)` gives you a simple vector of the lengths

Comment: So I guess just `which(lengths(mat) < 5 & lengths(mat) > 1, arr.ind = TRUE)`

Comment: @Sotos `lengths` will only return a vector. This two-liner will work: `lMat <- matrix(lengths(mat), 6)` and then `which(lMat > 1 & lMat < 5, arr.ind=TRUE)`.

Comment: @lmo `arr.ind = TRUE` takes care of that

Comment: @Sotos `arr.ind` on a vector has no effect

Comment: When I run `which(lengths(mat) < 5 & lengths(mat) > 1, arr.ind = TRUE)` I get the indices

Comment: he wants i and j, your line gives `[1]  3  7 13`

Comment: In my system I get correct output.

Comment: this must be an R version issue (the difference). In 3.3.0 you get a vector from `lengths(mat)` but it was probably improved to give the former format in more recent release

Comment: my R version is 3.3.1

Comment: So a version problem I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `lengths` from base R. As there are various comments about what outputs what in this case, here are my details,

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

 mat
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]     
[1,] Numeric,5 Numeric,4 Numeric,3 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0
[2,] 2         Numeric,5 3         Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0
[3,] Numeric,3 1         Numeric,5 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0
[4,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 1.358     Numeric,0 Numeric,0
[5,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 0.0223258 Numeric,0
[6,] Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 Numeric,0 1.493    

str(mat)
List of 36
 $ : num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ : num 2
 $ : num [1:3] 3 2 1
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num [1:4] 1 2 3 6
 $ : num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ : num 1
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num [1:3] 3 4 2
 $ : num 3
 $ : num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num 1.36
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num 0.0223
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num(0) 
 $ : num 1.49
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 6 6
```

Then,

```
m2 <- lengths(mat)
which(m2 < 5 & m2 > 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   3   1
#[2,]   1   2
#[3,]   1   3
```

In case you are using a version < 3.4.1, then a two step approach (as the one proposed by @lmo) will work, i.e.

```
m1 <- matrix(lengths(mat), 6) 
which(m1 > 1 & m1 < 5, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution:

```
lMat <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) sapply(x, length))
which(lMat > 1 & lMat < 5, arr.ind = TRUE)
```